# Show a login page to a user who is not logged in without LoginRequiredMixin / django

Tags: python, django

this is my code

```
class PostDetail(DetailView):
    model = Post

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = CommentForm()
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            if form.is_valid():
                comment = form.save(commit=False)
                comment.comment_owner = request.user
                comment.post = Post.objects.get(pk=kwargs['pk'])
                comment.save()
                return redirect('blog:detail', pk=kwargs['pk'])
            else:
                return redirect('blog:detail', pk=kwargs['pk'])
        else:
             ???
```

i added comment form in detailview
When a user who is not logged in attempts to add a comment, I want to display a login page.
i didn't add LoginRequiredMixin because anyone should be able to see the post.
any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# You just need to redirect to login page

views.py

from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

class PostDetail(DetailView):
    model = Post

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = CommentForm()
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            if form.is_valid():
                comment = form.save(commit=False)
                comment.comment_owner = request.user
                comment.post = Post.objects.get(pk=kwargs['pk'])
                comment.save()
                return redirect('blog:detail', pk=kwargs['pk'])
            else:
                return redirect('blog:detail', pk=kwargs['pk'])
        else:
             return redirect('login-user')


# add a namespace in your urls, so that the user can redirect to that namespace 'login-user'

urls.py

re_path(r'^login-admin/$', LoginView.as_view(), name='login-user'),
```